# How to print this format

Tags: java, stringbuilder, system.out

I want to print persons in this format where each person is in a column, and each person is delimited by a space or a tab, i.e.

John  Smith
 Male  Male
 
 01     02

How can I modify my toString() to print out in a nice format? Currently, each field and each person are printed out in a single line.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    persons.add(new Person("John", "Male", "01"));
    persons.add(new Person("Smith", "Male", "02"));
    persons.add(new Person("Jack", "Male", "03"));
    persons.add(new Person("Mary", "Female", "04"));
    persons.add(new Person("Alice", "Feamle", "05"));

    for(Person p : persons){
        System.out.print(p + " ");
    }
}

static class Person{

    private String name;
    private String sex;
    private String ID;

    public Person(String n, String s, String id){
        name = n;
        sex = s;
        ID = id;
    }

    public String toString(){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(ID + "\n");
        sb.append(name + "\n");
        sb.append(sex + "\n");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
}
```

What I really want is this format. I have a priority queue, and for debugging, I need to print out the contents of priority queue in this format.

Priority queue trace.

```
Here are the contents of our priority queue (sorted by priority) just before dequeueing each node when using the Manhattan priority function on puzzle04.txt.

    Step 0:    priority  = 4
               moves     = 0
               manhattan = 4
               3            
                0  1  3     
                4  2  5     
                7  8  6     

    Step 1:    priority  = 4    priority  = 6
               moves     = 1    moves     = 1
               manhattan = 3    manhattan = 5
               3                3            
                1  0  3          4  1  3     
                4  2  5          0  2  5     
                7  8  6          7  8  6     

    Step 2:    priority  = 4    priority  = 6    priority  = 6
               moves     = 2    moves     = 1    moves     = 2
               manhattan = 2    manhattan = 5    manhattan = 4
               3                3                3            
                1  2  3          4  1  3          1  3  0     
                4  0  5          0  2  5          4  2  5     
                7  8  6          7  8  6          7  8  6     

    Step 3:    priority  = 4    priority  = 6    priority  = 6    priority  = 6    priority  = 6
               moves     = 3    moves     = 3    moves     = 2    moves     = 3    moves     = 1
               manhattan = 1    manhattan = 3    manhattan = 4    manhattan = 3    manhattan = 5
               3                3                3                3                3            
                1  2  3          1  2  3          1  3  0          1  2  3          4  1  3     
                4  5  0          4  8  5          4  2  5          0  4  5          0  2  5     
                7  8  6          7  0  6          7  8  6          7  8  6          7  8  6     

    Step 4:    priority  = 4    priority  = 6    priority  = 6    priority  = 6    priority  = 6    priority  = 6
               moves     = 4    moves     = 3    moves     = 4    moves     = 2    moves     = 3    moves     = 1
               manhattan = 0    manhattan = 3    manhattan = 2    manhattan = 4    manhattan = 3    manhattan = 5
               3                3                3                3                3                3            
                1  2  3          1  2  3          1  2  0          1  3  0          1  2  3          4  1  3     
                4  5  6          0  4  5          4  5  3          4  2  5          4  8  5          0  2  5     
                7  8  0          7  8  6          7  8  6          7  8  6          7  0  6          7  8  6
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this just by overloading the toString() method, if each line is to print out properties of multiple objects

Comment: Please see my update. Thanks. The content is in a priority queue.How to print out that format? It's possible, because others did that.

Comment: I'm confused by your priority queue. Does my answer have the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `String.Format` method. I think it's exactly what you're looking for to format the string you return. Here's it's documentation [String.Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `get` methods for your `Person` class so that when iterating through each person, you can add each property of the person to a string, and then display it later. Like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PersonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

        persons.add(new Person("John", "Male", "01"));
        persons.add(new Person("Smith", "Male", "02"));
        persons.add(new Person("Jack", "Male", "03"));
        persons.add(new Person("Mary", "Female", "04"));
        persons.add(new Person("Alice", "Feamle", "05"));

        // Strings to display at the end of the iterations
        StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder(), sexes = new StringBuilder(), ids = new StringBuilder();

        for(Person p : persons) {
            // tab after each property
            names.append(p.getName() + "\t");
            sexes.append(p.getSex() + "\t");
            ids.append(p.getId() + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println(names);
        System.out.println(sexes);
        System.out.println(ids);
    }

    static class Person {

        private String name;
        private String sex;
        private String ID;

        public Person(String n, String s, String id) {
            name = n;
            sex = s;
            ID = id;
        }

        // getter methods to get the properties of this person
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public String getSex() {
            return sex;
        }
        public String getId() {
            return ID;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
John    Smith   Jack    Mary    Alice   
Male    Male    Male    Female  Feamle  
01      02      03      04      05
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this by overriding the `toString()` method. You have to write some string util method which will take `List` of person and builds the string representation of the list and return it. Once you done populating `Person` objects, call this util method.

For building the string, you can use `StringBuilder` object.

Util method will look something like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(Person p : persons){
    sb.append(p.getName()+"\t");
}
sb.append("\n")
for(Person p : persons){
    sb.append(p.getSex() + "\t");
}
sb.append("\n")
for(Person p : persons){
    sb.append(p.getID() + "\t");
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do three sets of iterations. Instead, you can just have three StringBuilders.

Answer (score 0):

A basic way of doing it would be this:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    persons.add(new Person("John", "Male", "01"));
    persons.add(new Person("Smith", "Male", "02"));
    persons.add(new Person("Jack", "Male", "03"));
    persons.add(new Person("Mary", "Female", "04"));
    persons.add(new Person("Alice", "Feamle", "05"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Person p : persons){
        sb.append(p.getName() + " ");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    for(Person p : persons){
        sb.append(p.getSex() + " ");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    for(Person p : persons){
        sb.append(p.getID() + " ");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
}

static class Person{

    private String name;
    private String sex;
    private String ID;

    public Person(String n, String s, String id){
        name = n;
        sex = s;
        ID = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Persons.size()){
        System.out.print(Persons.get(i).name + " ");
}
```

Comment: This is a very incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quick one would be given that number of persons is somehow limited:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    persons.add(new Person("John", "Male", "01"));
    persons.add(new Person("Smith", "Male", "02"));
    persons.add(new Person("Jack", "Male", "03"));
    persons.add(new Person("Mary", "Female", "04"));
    persons.add(new Person("Alice", "Feamle", "05"));

    StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sex = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder ID = new StringBuilder();
    String delimeter = "";

   for(Person p : persons){
       name.append(delimeter).append(p.name);
       sex.append(delimeter).append(p.sex);
       ID.append(delimeter).append(p.ID);
       delimeter = "\t";
   }

   System.out.println(name);
   System.out.println(sex);
   System.out.println(ID);
}
```

Output `John     Smith    Jack    Mary    Alice
      Male     Male     Male    Female  Feamle
      01       02       03      04      05`

Some additional concern might be if name is very long and breaks alignment.